# Output multiple summarized lists with KQL

Tags: kql

I want to output multiple lists of unique column values with KQL.

For instance for the following table:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | one |
| 1 | x | two |
| 1 | y | one |

I want to output

| K | V |
| --- | --- |
| A | [1] |
| B | [x,y] |
| C | [one, two] |

I accomplished this using summarize with make_list and 2 unions, been wondering if its possible to accomplish this in the same query without union?

Table
| distinct A
| summarize k="A", v= make_list(A)
union
Table
| distinct b
| summarize k="B", v= make_list(B)
...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your data set is reasonably-sized, you could try using the `narrow()` plugin: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/narrowplugin

```
datatable(A:int, B:string, C:string)
[
    1, 'x', 'one',
    1, 'x', 'two',
    1, 'y', 'one',
]
| evaluate narrow()
| summarize make_set(Value) by Column
```

| Column | set_Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | ["1"] |
| B | ["x","y"] |
| C | ["one","two"] |

---

Alternatively, you could use a combination of `pack_all()` and `mv-apply`

```
datatable(A:int, B:string, C:string)
[
    1, 'x', 'one',
    1, 'x', 'two',
    1, 'y', 'one',
]
| project p = pack_all()
| mv-apply p on (
    extend key = tostring(bag_keys(p)[0])
    | project key, value = p[key]
)
| summarize make_set(value) by key
```

| key | set_value |
| --- | --- |
| A | ["1"] |
| B | ["x","y"] |
| C | ["one","two"] |